# Xamarin.Android ActionBar logo click listener

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to handle my custom logo click on ActionBar.

```
 <style name="ReadingsActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Readings.ActionBar</item>
<item name="logo">@drawable/back</item>
<item name="android:logo">@drawable/back</item>
```

Style

I must compile on Android 4.4 and here is what I tried:

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(Xamarin.ActionbarSherlockBinding.Views.IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                var homeActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeActivity));
                StartActivity(homeActivity); ;
                break;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to handle my custom logo click on ActionBar.

You can follow the below steps to handle icon click on ActionBar;

1. Firstly, please make sure you are using `Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity` If not, please install `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` through nuget and inherit your activity from `AppCompatActivity`.
2. Secondly, please define your menu items in `Resource\menu\actionbar_items.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
         android:icon="@drawable/iconName"
         android:title="favorite"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
   </menu>
   ```
3. Inflate the menu in `OnCreateOptionsMenu`:

   ```
   public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
   {
       MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_items, menu);

       return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```
4. Handle the item click event in `OnOptionsItemSelected`:

   ```
   public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
   {
       switch (item.ItemId)
       {
           case Resource.Id.action_favorite:
               //do something
               break;
       }
       return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

Here is the complete Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "ActionbarClickDemo", MainLauncher = true,Theme ="@style/AppTheme")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar myToolbar = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.my_toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_items, menu);

        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.action_favorite:
                //do something
                break;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

For Creation of ActionBar, please refer to [Setting Up the App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html);

For Add Items to ActionBar, please refer to [Add Views and Action Providers](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/action-views.html)